# ASP.NET - Multiple Actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these two methods:

```
public List<ProntoCheckListSaveClass> updateProntoCheckList(List<ProntoCheckListSaveClass> items)
{
    tblJobsConnectionClass jobs = new tblJobsConnectionClass();
    return jobs.updateProntoCheckList(items);
}

public List<UserModel> PostTasks(List<CellModel> cells)
{
    List<UserModel> model = new List<UserModel>();

    if (cells == null)
    {
        UserModel nullModel = new UserModel();
        nullModel.name = "NF";
        nullModel.userName = "NF";
        model.Add(nullModel);
        return model;
    }
    else
    {
        tblJobsConnectionClass jobs = new tblJobsConnectionClass();   
        model.Add(jobs.PostScheduledTasks(cells));
        return model;
    }
}
```

When I try to call updateProntoCheckList, I get this error:

> {\"Message\":\"An error has
>   occurred.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"Multiple actions were found that
>   match the request:
>   \r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Models.ProntoCheckListSaveClass]
>   updateProntoCheckList(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Models.ProntoCheckListSaveClass])
>   on type
>   LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Controllers.tblJobsController\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Models.UserModel]
>   PostTasks(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Models.CellModel])
>   on type
>   LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Controllers.tblJobsController\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\",\"StackTrace\":\"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatc..."  0x795c9000

trying to call this method in objective-c

Comment: Are you using WebAPI?

Comment: What happens if you try to access one of the methods locally?

Comment: You have two methods with the same name in your WebAPI class.